# How to remove shininess from model in Three.JS

Tags: three.js

[image]

Trying to recreate the image with the exact same model but I just can't nail down the lighting.

The version I recreated has a weird shine to the edges that I do not know how to get rid of.

[image]

The website that I am trying to recreate and is where I downloaded the resource from is

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/iphone-x-c143efdc2cc54d7eaaf48b197b92885d

```
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: myCanvas, 
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    light2.castShadow = false;
    scene.add(light2);

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('scene.gltf', handle_load, undefined, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    var mesh;

    function handle_load(gltf) {

        console.log(gltf);
        mesh = gltf.scene;
        console.log(mesh.children[0]);
        mesh.children[0].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
        scene.add( mesh );
        mesh.position.z = -20;
        mesh.rotation.x = 0;
        mesh.rotation.y = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The model looks nice if I import it to the following `three.js` based [glTF-Viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/).

[image]

I suggest you use a similar lighting setup: A combination of an `AmbientLight` and `DirectionalLight` with an environment map. Also set the property [physicallyCorrectLights](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.physicallyCorrectLights) of your instance of `WebGLRenderer` to `true`. The viewer is open source so you can inspect the details in the following file: [viewer.js](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/master/src/viewer.js)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am pretty new to three.js, how do I add an environment map?

Comment: You can do it similar to this example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf. Check out, how the `envMap` property of the material is set.

Answer (score 0):

Mungen87's answer is solid, but if you just want to manually remove shininess from everything in your scene, you can easily (and very quickly!) run:

```
scene.traverse(i => {if (i.isMesh) i.material.shininess = 0})
```